# run multiple Jars in a given order with nodejs

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I want to run two jars one after the other with nodejs but it seems like my program only stars the first jar :

The exec function : 
execute a single shell command where "cmd" is a string

```
exports.exec = function(cmd, cb){
    // this would be way easier on a shell/bash script :P
    var child_process = require('child_process');
    var parts = cmd.split(/\s+/g);
    var p = child_process.spawn(parts[0], parts.slice(1), {stdio: 'inherit'});
    p.on('exit', function(code){
        var err = null;
        if (code) {
            err = new Error('command "'+ cmd +'" exited with wrong status code "'+ code +'"');
            err.code = code;
            err.cmd = cmd;
        }
        if (cb) cb(err);
    });
};
```

Execute multiple commands in series this could be replaced by any flow control lib :

```
exports.series = function(cmds, cb){
    var execNext = function(){
        exports.exec(cmds.shift(), function(err){
            if (err) {
                cb(err);
            } else {
                if (cmds.length) execNext();
                else cb(null);
            }
        });
    };
    execNext();
};
```

My use case :

```
shell.series([
  `java -jar ${appDir}integration-tests/e2e-tests/tests/perf/uxcast-stub-0.27.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`,
  `java -jar ${appDir}integration-tests/e2e-tests/tests/perf/uxcast-app-0.27.0.jar`,
], err => {
  if (err !== null) {
    console.log('UXCAST ERROR -> ' + err);
    return;
  }
  expect(startBrowser()).toBe('stuff');
  done();
});
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Your code seems OK to me, do you get any error ?

Comment: nop, there's no error ... but I'm pretty sure the 2nd jar does't execute

Comment: _I'm pretty sure_ could you check that by putting a `console.log` at the moment of the execution ?

Comment: The second jar doesn't get executed I have logs allover the code, only the first jar get executed ...

Comment: I mocked the executing part by using a `setTimeout` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hnf6ncp9/). It works, so either the first jar doesn't exit, either the second one doesn't work properly.